# sql function take name from table and return its salary from the same table

Tags: sql, oracle, function, oracle11g

I have table customers with two fields name and salary. I need to make a function to 
take name as a parameter and return matched salary form customers table

```
CREATE TABLE customers
(
customer_name varchar2(50),
customer_salary number;
);
CREATE FUNCTION customer (c_name IN customers.customer_name%type)
RETURN number; /*return value type*/
IS
sal customers.customer_salary%type;
BEGIN /*Begin*/
SELECT customer_salary into sal
FROM customers
WHERE (c_name = sal);
RETURN sal;
END /*End*/
```

I did this but I can't find the solution !

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare customer name with salary..what you want to do instead is compare the passed parameter c_name with the customer name field in the table

```
CREATE FUNCTION customer (c_name IN customers.customer_name%type)
RETURN number; /*return value type*/
IS
sal customers.customer_salary%type;
BEGIN /*Begin*/
SELECT customer_salary into sal
FROM customers
WHERE (customer_name=c_name);
RETURN sal;
END /*End*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you are trying to do will very likely fail in any kind of real-life situation, and the failure has nothing to do with SQL or any other code or technology-related thing. Names are not unique. What if you pass in a parameter like 'Smith' or 'James Smith' (in English-speaking countries) and you have ten or a thousand customers with the same name? The function will throw an error, with a message about "too many rows returned."

If needed for any reason, you could return a list (table - sorted if desired) of all customers with the same name, and with the salary for each of them. You could do that very easily in SQL (no need for a function).

Funny business too, where customers have salaries; I would like to be a customer of your business!   :-)